# Why ajax reloads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax + jquery script and when I execute it (click the button) it reloads the page.

script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).on('click', '.image-remove-btn', function (e){
    var img = $(this).closest('.thumbs');
    var id = img.attr('data-id');
  
    $.ajax({
        url: admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {deletedId : id},
        success: function( data ) {
            img.remove();
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML of element that should be removed:

```
<div class="thumbs ui-droppable">
                <div class="inner ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-thumb="0">
                    <img data-id="32949" src="https://badzingerauto.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/NISSAN__QASHQAI__1-5_dCi_106_Acenta__inc-__inc-__2009__BC501CF-e01-350x205.jpg">
                    <div class="inner-hover">
                       <button class="image-remove-btn butterbean-remove-image"> <!-- <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> Font Awesome fontawesome.com -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is the button in a `<form>`? Basic code shown will not cause page to reload by itself

Comment: comment ajax request and check does click event reload page?

Comment: Please share the full code in your question.

Comment: What is `.image-remove-btn`, and where is it located? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: @Greg-- Script without ajax doesn't reload the page. It does it's job (delete images) but when I save changes - images are not deleted, so I thought that ajax will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Charlieft is correct you can change your code as follows to prevent the reload

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.image-remove-btn', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var img = $(this).closest('.thumbs');
    var id = img.attr('data-id');
  
    $.ajax({
        url: admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: {deletedId : id},
        success: function( data ) {
            img.remove();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: One more problem: I don't know what to paste in `url`. `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` gets error in console, `ajaxurl` gets it too. Error is: `load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.6.4:2 POST https://badzingerauto.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_fs_blog_admin=true 400`

Comment: you need to register an ajax action to call, I recommend looking at a tutorial to see how it works. Something like this [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/). be careful trough you probably only want authorized users to be able to do this